# Код не удаляется на сайте

Tags: html, css

Недавно выгрузил сайт и решил его сразу же отредактировать немного.

Начал с надписать под поисковым окном и столкнулся с тем что стили вообще не применяются, то есть как они были последние выгружены на хостинг так и остались.
Я удалил старый не нужный мне стиль и переписал на новый подходящий сохранил все через notepad++ и пошел смотреть на сайте через Chrome , в итоге ничего не изменилось от слова совсем , обычная серая надпись без стилей...

Открыл код элемента а там те самые старые стили которые были удалены, объясните почему все так вот выходит?
Сайт говорит что есть решение вопроса но это совсем другое , не мой случай!!!!!!

Прикрепляю скрины

P.S. сильно не ругайте мои коды я самоучка да и начал только месяц назад)[image: срин]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+s в нотпаде)? или ctrl+r в хроме чтобы обновиться без кэша ) Файл загрузить на сервер вместо старого (если не локально развернуто) )?

Comment: ctrl+s и ctrl+r прожимаю 
а вот про файл загрузить подробнее можно? что за сервер ?
У меня есть хостинг а там дальше не знаю , на сайте где хостинг покупал ничего такого нет
Я самоучка собирал все на opencart может поможете каким разъяснением ?

Comment: ну, вы меняете файл локально. А файлик то лежит на сервере, и сайт смотрит на файл на сервере. надо подключиться по FTP и заменить файл на сервере чтобы что-то поменялось.

Comment: Может там просто какой-нибудь  cloudflare кеширует стиль, и они не обновляются
Можно проверить: дописать в конце ссылки на css файл что-то типа ?1=1, если изменения появились то надо лезть в клаудфлер и включать режим разработчика